# Sphere-plane intersection - how to find centre?

Tags: geometry, vectors

> Suppose $S$ is a sphere and $P$ is a plane. If the intersection of $S$ and $P$ is not empty, then the intersection is a circle.

I understand this and I am doing a problem where a sphere of radius 2, centred at the origin, meets a plane $P$. I need to find the centre of the circle formed by the intersection. I am struggling to see the geometry of this.

I have been 'told' that the centre lies on the line passing through the origin and that is normal to the plane. But I can't appreciate why.

Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: Cannot you take 3 points of the intersection and calculate de centre using them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy: have a look at the picture below. If you have any other question feel free to ask...

Hope this helps

[image]